# Sublime Text: Switching files in different folders

Tags: sublimetext

I have opened a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) project in `Sublime Text` and I am working on windows environment.
I need to switch among `.cpp` and `.h` files. There is a command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> which can switch these files if they are in the same folder. but my files are placed as follow:

- `.h` in `myfolder/include/subfolder/`
- `.cpp` in `myfolder/src/subfolder/`

The file names are same, they just differ in extensions. Right now I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, but I want single command to do that.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It might not be *exactly* what you want but here is a workaround to accomplish what you ask for: if you download and install the [CTags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags) plugin for `Sublime`, you will be able to:

- Build tags with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> will make you jump to definition (from header to source) of what is under your cursor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to "jump back" (to header)

**[EDIT]**

- It seems someone has implemented a [plugin](https://github.com/jturcotte/SublimeSwitchFileDeluxe) to accomplish what you want (didn't test it though, note that the README says that it will look for matches outside of the current folder but only in already opened files)
- FWIW, the original feature is in `Packages/Default/switch_file.py` (also you might want to have a look to `Vim` equivalent [code](https://gist.github.com/nornagon/2025487))

Answer (score 1):

[Switch File Deluxe](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Switch%20File%20Deluxe) does exactly what you want. It overrides <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.